# Some models are not listed in user permissions

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-permissions

I am working with Django 1.8 and with its `admin` app.

And when I try to set permissions for my "staff" users I can't see **all** my models. There are only some, and I don't understand because this should be done automatically, right?

I am registering my model in `admin.py`

```
admin.site.register(Promo, PromoAdmin)
```

This is my `models.py`

```
class Promo(models.Model):
  id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
  code = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
  enabled = models.BooleanField(blank=False)
  amount = models.FloatField()
  max_uses = models.IntegerField()

  class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'promo'

  def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

```
$ ./manage.py syncdb --all
usage: manage.py syncdb [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}] [--settings SETTINGS]
                    [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH] [--traceback] [--no-color]
                    [--noinput] [--no-initial-data] [--database DATABASE]
manage.py syncdb: error: unrecognized arguments: --all
```

**UPDATE**
They are not even in the table django_contenttype. In general how a model is added to this table? I am not working with migrations, mi _meta.managed = False

Comment: If the app is included in `INSTALLED_APPS`, then Django should create the missing permissions when you run `./manage.py migrate`.

Comment: Or otherwise you can do `./manage.py syncdb --all`.

Comment: @ShangWang I ran `syncdb` alone, because `--all` returns error

Comment: @Alasdair it is included... Actually a lot of other models are shown

Comment: So does `migrate` work? Can you update your question with error backtrace for having `--all` option?

Comment: @ShangWang no, `No migrations to apply.`

Comment: Can you update your question with error backtrace for having `--all` option  when you run `syncdb`?